# Помогите с таблицей HTML

Tags: html5

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <title>Статистика 6 классов</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 style="text-align:center">Стата 6 классов<br>успеваемость</h1>
  <table height="50px" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center"><strong style="text-align:center">Статистика</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Класс</td>
      <td>Кол-во учеников</td>
      <td>Спортсмены</td>
      <td>Отличники</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6А</td>
      <td>25 м. 15д.</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6Б</td>
      <td>19 м. 16 д.</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6В</td>
      <td>12 м. 10д.</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6Г</td>
      <td>16 м. 4 д.</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

я хочу сделать "Статистика" на всю строку в таблице.

Comment: Добавь атрибут rowspan=4 к td статистика

Comment: плюс ещё можно иногда прибегать к подобным ресурсам -> https://iksweb.ru/tools/generator-table-html/  для большего понимания что происходит при построении таблиц

Answer (score -1, accepted):

А нельзя убрать статистику из таблицы и немного сместить вправо?
Вот код:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Статистика 6 классов</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 style="text-align:center">Стата 6 классов<br>успеваемость</h1>
  <table height="50px" border="1">
    <tr>
      <strong style="margin-left: 125px;">Статистика</strong>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Класс</td>
      <td>Кол-во учеников</td>
      <td>Спортсмены</td>
      <td>Отличники</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6А</td>
      <td>25 м. 15д.</td>
      <td>13</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6Б</td>
      <td>19 м. 16 д.</td>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6В</td>
      <td>12 м. 10д.</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6Г</td>
      <td>16 м. 4 д.</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```